# Angular Cannot match any routes when running on HTTPS

Tags: .net, angular, iis

I have a Angular application generated by the Radzen IDE running on IIS. In the application is a anchor tag that points to a .Net API that is used to download files. The href of that anchor looks like this:

`https://[AngularApp.mydomain.com]/api/ServerMethods/DownloadFile?fName=[NameOfTheFile.pdf]&ID=[SomeID]`

When the application runs on http and I click the link, the download works as expected. When the application runs on https, I get a "Cannot match any routes" error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL 
Segment: 'api/ServerMethods/DownloadFile'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 
'api/ServerMethods/DownloadFile'
```

When I use Postman to call the API directly, the download works, even with https. It also works with https when I do a right click on the download link and click "Save link as". The error only occurs when I try to open the link from within the Angular application, or when I open the link directly in a browser.

Is there something I need to configure in IIS? I tried different settings on the Application Pool for the .Net CLR Version or the Managed Pipeline Mode, with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `<a href="your/url"` instead of `<a routerLink="your/url"`, because here you are navigating outside of your angular application